# How to store multiple xml values to java

Tags: java, sql, arrays, xml, loops

My problem is how will I pass the value of multiple values of xml:

```
       <newInsert>
    <src>BUDDY</src> 
    <dest>12345</dest> 
    <svcFlag>15</svcFlag> 
    <svcClass>0</svcClass>
    <svcTypeID>ABCD</svcTypeID> 
    <callCode></callCode>
    <prefix></prefix>

    <src>BUDDY</src> 
    <dest>1245</dest> 
    <svcFlag>15</svcFlag> 
    <svcClass>1</svcClass>
    <svcTypeID>ABDC</svcTypeID> 
    <callCode></callCode>
    <prefix></prefix>

    <src>BUDDY</src> 
    <dest>12321</dest> 
    <svcFlag>15</svcFlag> 
    <svcClass>1</svcClass>
    <svcTypeID>AABS</svcTypeID> 
    <callCode></callCode>
    <prefix></prefix>

</newInsert>
```

how will I store it now and past it to the prepared Statement?

I'm already done storing single valued xml:

```
<newInsert>
    <src>BUDDY</src> 
    <dest>12345</dest> 
    <svcFlag>15</svcFlag> 
    <svcClass>0</svcClass>
    <svcTypeID>ABCD</svcTypeID> 
    <callCode></callCode>
    <prefix></prefix>
</newInsert>
```

I was able to store it in a variable:

```
for(int i = 0; i < nList.getLength(); i++) {
    Node nodes = nList.item(i);

 if (nodes.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
    Element element = (Element) nodes;

  src_name = element.getElementsByTagName("src").item(0).getTextContent();
  dest = element.getElementsByTagName("dest").item(0).getTextContent();
  svcFlag = element.getElementsByTagName("svcFlag").item(0).getTextContent();
  svcClass = element.getElementsByTagName("svcClass").item(0).getTextContent();
  svcTypeID = element.getElementsByTagName("svcTypeID").item(0).getTextContent();
  callCode =  element.getElementsByTagName("callCode").item(0).getTextContent();
  prefix = element.getElementsByTagName("prefix").item(0).getTextContent();     
 }
}
```

these variables are being passed to prepared statement:

```
st= con.prepareStatement(ins_query);
st.setString(1, src_name);
st.setString(2, dest);
st.setString(3, svcFlag);
st.setString(4, svcClass);
st.setString(5, svcTypeID);
st.setString(6, callCode);
st.setString(7, prefix);
```

Comment: You could either run the insert script in loop or use batch insert

Answer (score 0):

You can create new object like this

```
public class Data{
 private src_name;
 private dest 
 private svcFlag 
 private svcClass 
 private svcTypeID 
 private callCode
 private prefix  
     //getters and setters
}
```

Then in loop you can create new data object for every iteration and store it to list

```
List<String> nods = new ArrayList()<>;
......
if (nodes.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
    Element element = (Element) nodes;
 Data data = new Data();
 data.setSrc_name(element.getElementsByTagName("src").item(0).getTextContent());
 data.setDest(element.getElementsByTagName("dest").item(0).getTextContent());
 ............    
}
```

And then you can iterate over **nods** list and create statement for every data object like this

```
nods.stream().forEach(nod->{
st= con.prepareStatement(ins_query);
st.setString(1,nod.getSrc_Name);
st.setString(2,nod.getDest);
.................
});
```